# Sending push notification to development app, with production server certificate

Tags: ios, ssl, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

We are building application with support for push notifications. So far, we implemented the push server with development certificate, using sandbox mode. The moment when application is published at app store, web server will need to be switched to production mode using production certificate. 
The questions is, if we switch the server to production, does the development instances of application still gonna receive push notifications? If no, what should be made to have available push notifications on Production and Development at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The development instances won't receive push notifications when you switch to the production certificate (and connect to APNS production server). In addition, trying to send notifications to the development device tokens will result in an error (since development device tokens are invalid in production environment). You should remove the development device tokens from your DB prior to switching your server to production mode. This will save you a lot of trouble.

Here's a relevant quote from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html):

> The most common problem is an invalid device token. **If the token came
>   from the sandbox environment**, such as when you are testing a
>   development build in house, **you can't send it to the production push
>   service**. Each push environment will issue a different token for the
>   same device or computer. If you do send a device token to the wrong
>   environment, the push service will see that as an invalid token and
>   discard the notification.
>
> Note: **It is recommended that you run a separate instance of your
>   provider for each push environment to avoid the problem of sending
>   device tokens to the wrong environment**.

If you do need to continue supporting push notifications for the development instances of the app, you must distinguish in your DB between development and production device tokens (i.e. mark which device tokens are development tokens and which are production). You'll have to maintain separate connections to the production and sandbox APNS servers using different certificates for each, and you'll have to use the correct connection when sending a notification to a device token (based on how it's marked in your DB).